# Decoding a sql function

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm working with some queries that someone has written but has now left the organisation.

To begin with, here's a table-valued function - could someone please help me understand what its trying to do.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfSplitString]
(    
    @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
    Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT
 
    SET @StartIndex = 1
    IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
    BEGIN
        SET @Input = @Input + @Character
    END
 
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)
         
        INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)
         
        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
    END
 
    RETURN
END
```

Thanks

Comment: It splits the `@input` string at every occurrence of `@character` ascthe name suggests

Comment: Well it quite clearly takes a string and returns it split into rows using the supplied delimeter; it's even clearer when you create the function and run it. It's doing exactly the same as the built-in function `string_split()`

Comment: Thanks for that! but we surely cant tell what @input parameters are, correct?

Comment: Find all the function calls to see what is being passed.

Comment: Prior to SQL Server having `STRING_SPLIT` available as a built-in, I'm pretty sure every sufficiently large system ended up having a home-grown string splitter in it...

Comment: And the good news is that a new future update to SQL Server will (finally) be catering for row ordering in `string_split`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table-valued function that divides a text into substring rows depending on a separator character. Returns a single-column table with substrings as rows.

Value is the name of the column. If any of the input parameters are nvarchar or nchar, this function returns nvarchar. Otherwise, varchar is returned. The return type's length is the same as the string argument's length. For Example:

[image]

Hence, as metioned by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7644018/paul-t) : Find all the function calls to see what is being passed.

STRING_SPLIT inputs a string that has delimited substrings, and inputs one character to use as the delimiter or separator. STRING_SPLIT outputs a single-column table whose rows contain the substrings. The name of the output column is value.

Comment: Note that we recently extended string_split to have an optional second argument to let you emit a second column of ordinals for the relative position within the original string.